# Integrating OpenCover with xUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, opencover

I am relatively new to the Visual Studio IDE and working on a C# project for which I am using xUnit framework to do testing.

I have planned to use the "OpenCover" tool for determining the code coverage. Could someone tell me how to integrate this tool with Visual Studio?

Comment: [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) is a command line tool it doesn't really integrate with Visual Studio. I just have a command line open and run it when I need to.

Comment: Hello Shaun.. I got to know from GIT website that Opencover doesnt support windows XP environment (before a yr).. Is there any support added for operability with xp now?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCover itself is a command-line-only tool. In order to present the results "nicely" you need a visualiser, such as [ReportGenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) (which will work fine with xUnit) or [OpenCoverUI](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688/view/Discussions) (which only *claims* to work with MSTest and NUnit).